# How to change "Copied to clipboard" toast message in share menu

Tags: java, android, toast

I have been using the below code to share the text in respective apps. If I select the copy to clipboard option in the share menu, After copying it is showing toast with the message copied to clipboard. Can we modify copied to clipboard message into our desired message? Any help much appreciated.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
sendIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "Text to copy");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Product via"));
```

Comment: IMO I think it's not possible because since the whole thing is provided by system itself ... I would recommend you to create your own sharing layout if needed and customize it..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
clipboard.setText("Text to copy");
clipboard.getText();
```

Comment: If I am not wrong he wants an answer to how to modify the toast message not how to copy text to clipboard

Comment: Javed, I want to change the toast message. How your suggestion will help here?

Comment: Can you send me more code?  May I fully understand your question